# Paypal buy now buttons redirect

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, paypal, payment

I have 4 different buy now buttons in my website which have 8 different redirect urls (4 payment types with success and error for each one). I want to apply auto return. I go to the selling tools option on Paypal and turn "Auto Return" to ON.  But i need to enter a url to redirect them to. I want to redirect each button to a different url, how can i do this?

Comment: Please add a bit of code showing how the buttons are created.

Comment: It's the standard code given by Paypal no editing on those from what I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine to enable Auto Return and set a return URL there. If you specify a return URL in your individual buttons, it will override whatever you have set up within your PayPal profile.

Comment: The website is live and I thought I could try this but I couldn't find such a suggestion anywhere. I will give it a try! Thanks

Comment: It works. Paypal does override the url given on the preferences.